# smtp.send failure sending email message from client machine

Tags: vb.net

```
        Mail.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(test@gmail.com)
        Mail.To.Add("exc@gmail.com")

        Mail.Subject = "Test"
        Mail.Body = "Test"
        Try
            Dim mySmtp As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server")
            mySmtp.Send(Mail)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: ex.message is saying just failure sending email.

Comment: Are you adding your credentials?

Comment: if we add credentials then it will work for all the users?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you hard code your credentials into the code above, then everything sent with the above code will be sent with your credentials.

Comment: i wrote this code in my application. i didn't add any credentials.

Comment: You have to add credentials for your gmail account. What that will do is authenticate your Gmail account and send your email. Otherwise, without credentials, I could copy your code and send emails under your name.

Comment: @keyboardP: OP is not using gmail as a server, he's just sending mail to his gmail account.

Comment: @Suresh: I'm assuming that you're replacing "server" in your code with an actual server name. Are you sure the server is valid and allows relay mail?

Comment: @Joel Etherton - Ah, I took it to mean `server` was replaced by the Gmail server. You're right, I shouldn't have made that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the your Anti Virus as they can block SMTP calls.